# How can I avoid sp.TOption type when using sp.unpack()?

Tags: smartpy, types

Within my smartpy contract, I want to convert from one type into another using `sp.pack()` and `sp.unpack`.

Below is an example of the method I am trying to use, converting a string to bytes.

```
        myString = sp.local("myString", "dummyString")
        packedString = sp.pack(myString.value)
        myBytes = sp.unpack(packedString, t = sp.TBytes)
```

The problem is the type of the output I get is

`sp.TOption(sp.TBytes)`

when what I wanted was just

`sp.TBytes`

What else should I do to make sure the type isn't `sp.TOption`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sp.unpack` gives you an option (because Michelson gives an option when you call `UNPACK`) that you need to open.

You can do it like this

```
        myBytes = sp.unpack(packedString, t = sp.TBytes).open_some()
```

if you're sure that packedString is indeed a packed `sp.TBytes`.

If you're not 100% sure, you can add an optional error message to `open_some()`.